# Redirect all pdfs to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i'm trying to redirect an url such as:

http://www.example.co.uk/pdfs/example-file.pdf

http://www.example.co.uk/files/example-file.pdf

http://www.example.co.uk/documents/example-file.pdf

To the base domain, http://www.example.co.uk/

**With**

```
# PDFs on old site, redirect them
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?pdf/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?files/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?documents/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END PDFs on old site, redirect them
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct rules are:

```
# PDFs on old site, redirect them
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(/?pdfs/.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(/?files/.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(/?documents/.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END PDFs on old site, redirect them
```